# Alternatives to LEFT JOIN in the following query

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization

Here are my tables

```
Invoice
---------------
Id| Number | Amount
1 |   001  |  10
```

```
Note
---------------
Id| Number | Amount
2 |   002  |  20
```

and there is a table called booking date, in which the data is stored as such

```
DocumentBookingDate
-------------------------
NoteId| InvoiceId | Date
 NULL |   1       | 02-02-2022
  2   |   NULL    | 02-03-2022
```

In the DocumentBookingDate table the invoiceId is the foriegnKey to ID of invoice and similarly for the noteId

I am writing a query to get a union all of these tables left joining with the documentBookingDate , however the query performance is very slow.
If I remove the left join the query runs quickly again.
There can also be a case where the invoice or note does not have a booking date .
My query (Edited for brevity)

```
 SELECT inv.Id as ID, inv.Number as Number, inv.Amount, dbd.Date as Amount from Invoice inv
 LEFT JOIN DocumentBookingDate dbd on dbd .InvoiceId = inv.Id

UNION ALL 

SELECT note.Id as ID, note.Number as Number, note.Amount, dbd.Date as Amount from Note note
 LEFT JOIN DocumentBookingDate dbd on dbd.NoteId = note.Id
```

Moving left join outside the union slows the query down even further

Link to the plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1XpEQkdh

Comment: Why do you think the `LEFT JOIN` is the blame? What does the query plan look like? Do you table(s) have relevant indexes on them to aid the query?

Comment: Ive checked the other indexes ,the documentbookingdate table has 2 FK indexes on noteId and incvoiceId . Removing the left join and the column in select gives a faster result , in the execution plan it is showing a nested loop, I think thats the issue

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1XpEQkdh

Comment: The age of mechanically transforming your input code to optimize is *largely* behind us now. Modern compilers or optimizers are far better at performing such mechanical transformations than humans are.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you please suggest some tools to optimize my query

Comment: The plan is materializing a big search of 282k and 310k rows in memory. That means there are probably missing indexes for those left joins. Add `create index ix1 on DocumentBookingDate (InvoiceId);` and `create index ix2 on DocumentBookingDate (NoteId);`. See [plan](https://checktheplan.com/?p=8073e6a859ab4f2c8dbe250f42847f89&l=ah).

Comment: Ther's some really horrible stuff in that plan, none of which has anything to do with your question as presented. `DocumentBookingDate` has no good index. `Shipment` has a key lookup, needs an `INCLUDE` on the index. Use of `NOLOCK` (bad idea). Use of `CONVERT(date` instead of datetime ranges. You seem to have full text search, possibly inside a view, you should avoid that if possible. You might be able to use `OUTER APPLY` to get this unioned join working better.

Comment: I do agree, the query you've given us and the query in your plan are *nothing* alike. The `LEFT JOIN` might be contributing, but there's plenty of other issues in that query before the `JOIN` probably becomes the root performance problem.

Comment: I was able to convert the query , now I have the following plan, https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryg1af9oh
here the sort is coming to 63% of total cost, is it possible to fix the performance of the same ?